# locating similar values in two separate files

Tags: python

I have two separate files in the following format:

```
File 1:
Polygon_Id::User_Id::Movie_ID::Rating
02143       69          1183     5   
02143       75          3006     4   
02143       89          1196     3   
02143       32           590     2   
02143       11           593     5   

file 2:
User_Id::Gender::Age::Occupation::ZipCode
  1        F      1      10        48067
  2        M      56     16        70072
  3        M      25     15        55117....
```

My job is: I have to find the User_Ids in file 1 whose Movie Ids match, and then from file 2 find the ages of these users

My Code so far is:

```
with open('c:/Python27/file1.txt','r+') as f:
data=f.read()
data=[line.split() for line in data.splitlines()]


import numpy as np

from itertools import groupby, combinations
key1=lambda x:x[2]

for p,q in groupby(sorted(data,key=key1),key1):
    rating_list=list(map(lambda x:x[3],q))
    rating_list=np.array(rating_list)

    with open('c:/Python27/file2.txt','r+') as f1:
      user_data=f1.read()
      user_data=[line.split() for line in user_data.splitlines()]
      user_data=np.array(user_data)

      for i,j in groupby(sorted(user_data,key=lambda x:x[0]),lambda x:x[0]):
          if p==i:
              user_age=list(map(lambda x:x[2],j))
              user_age=[float(n) for n in user_age]
              user_age=np.array(user_age)
              print i,p,user_age
```

## output

```
1009 1009 ['50']
1013 1013 ['56']...
```

Ideally there should be more values of ages in the output and not one as I'm getting.

Comment: I know the numpy seems redundant but I've to do a few opearations with the output.

Comment: can you attach a sample of your files..what you are trying to do is a bit unclear to me

Comment: i had to find a list of the ratings as well, which i have done, I grouped the data w.r.t the Movie_Id and got a list of the ratings.

Comment: @Dave_30: this part is not clear: "My job is: I have to find the User_Ids in file 1 whose Movie Ids match, and then from file 2 and find the ages of these users"

Comment: if you see the format of file 1, there are certain users who have rated the same movies. So for these users (represented here by User_id) the value of Movie_id is the same. I have grouped these users together. I've to find the ages of this group of users from file 2